# PyGI install on Windows cannot find Python installation

Tags: python, pygtk, gobject

I tried to install PyGI with the windows installer available here : http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/?source=navbar

I use Python 3.3 on Windows 7 x64.

The setup started and said that no available Python install was found. The setup invites me to choose manually a python installation Path but even if I select my "C:\Python33" path, it continues to say "No compatible Python was found".

I first thought that Python 3 was not supported... and even if I select my "C:\Python27" path, no changes.

Any idea ? I searched for some information on this error, but I didn't find anything... :(

Please help! Thanks :)

Comment: maybe you installed a 64 bit python but the package only compatible with 32bit?

Comment: Oh. I didn't think about that. My Python is a 64-bit so it seems I cannot use PyGObject...

Comment: FWIW I don't think there is anything in the source code which would prevent PyGObject from working on 64-bit Windows.  It's more likely that you cannot use *those* PyGObject packages, not that you cannot use PyGObject.

Comment: @nemequ There is no code here, it's only the PyGi Setup which cannot find any installed Python and I don't know why

Comment: I meant in the PyGObject source code, not your code.  In other words, it should be possible to compile PyGObject for 64-bit Windows/Python, it may just be that *those* packages didn't do that.  Or maybe it's just that the installer doesn't recognize the 64-bit Python install even though it contains 64-bit packages.

Comment: Also, you should file a bug against the sourceforge project—StackOverflow is a terrible place for this kind of question.  Unless the creator of those packages follows StackOverflow (unlikely) you're not likely to get a useful response.

Comment: The error is still present, I added a ticket on Sourceforge: https://sourceforge.net/p/pygobjectwin32/tickets/4/

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem trying to install `pygi`. I believe in order for the installation to detect Python you need to make sure that Python is in your system path. You can look up how to do this or just re-run the Python installation again.  The problem I had is that once I installed `pygi`, importing `gi` failed.